# Give a name to a generic Scala case class parametrized by a specific type

Tags: scala, generics

I have this case class

```scala
case class MyNormalClass[T](
  data: Option[T] = None,
  someOtherStuff: Option[Boolean] = None
)
```

and I want to define a type `MyParametrizedClass` that is just when `MyNormalClass[String]`. It seems like I can do this,

```scala
case class MyParametrizedClass() extends MyNormalClass[String]
```

but this seems kind of weird and I'm not sure it actually works, I wanted something simpler, like `val MyParametrizedClass = MyNormalClass[String]`.

Comment: Maybe `type MyParametrizedClass  = MyNormalClass[String]`? - May I ask, what is the motivation? What is the meta-problem you want to solve?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `Wrong top statement declaration`. I guess my motivation is to have my types defined in one file because my actual class names are quite long, so I don't want to do `MyPrettLongClassName[MyPrettyLongParametrizingClassName]` in the file that actually does something, but you're right I don't really need to do this.

Comment: I can be more specific. I am refactoring code where `MyParametrizedClass` used to be the type it was using but now I want to write `MyNormalClass` because I want one of the variables inside to be of different types, and this seemed like the fastest way to refactor it in the file where all the types are defined without having to change any other code.

Comment: `type` has to be inside an `object` it can be a `package object` also you would need to alias the companion object. **cats** has a couple of examples of such aliases.

Comment: For example like these ones here: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/package.scala#L44